# Reading cli in Nodejs explanation required

Tags: node.js, process, command-line-interface, listener, stdin

```
process.stdin.on('data',function(data){input_std_in+=data});
```

What is the correct explanation for the above piece of code. I am new to Node.js and have found many variations of this on the net, but I am still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The   `process.stdin` is used to read data from commandline (Simple Explaination) For more see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

So below you are waiting for `data event` of stdin ie you wait for user to type some data in terminal ,you read it and append it to some string.As `node js (javascript)` is `event driven` ,it  waits for some event to happen get the data from that event and use it further ,like in the script below it appends to already declared variable.

```
let input_std_in="";
    process.stdin.on('data',function(data){
      console.log("Data",data.toString())
      
      input_std_in+=data.toString()
      
      });
```

See working [here](https://repl.it/join/ymwqokzp-shubhamdixit863)